# create stackoverflow like url for search in node.js and javascript

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting

I want to change my page's URL with search item like stackoverflow and also display the page with the newly created URL,every time I hit the URL in new tab.

Like if I search using 'natures photography' which retrieves a photo named 'sunset in a village' then the URL should be like this: http://localhost:8080/sunset-in-a-village

How to do it with Node.js / Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I search using 'natures photography' which retrieves a photo named 'sunset in a village'

What do you mean exactly? Search often return not one item.
I suggest that result is set and have url like `/seach/natures-photography` and one of finded item have url `/photo/sunset-in-a-village`

```
    app.get('/search/:query', function(req, res, next) {
        // client send already dashed and lowercase query
        var query = req.params.query; // natures-photography
        // render result page. Each image have url like /photo/:dashed-lowercase-name
    })
   ... 
   app.get('/photo/:name', function(req, res, next) {
        var name = req.params.name; // sunset-in-a-village
        name = name.replace('-', ' '); // remove dash from name and find image by original lowercase-name  
        // render chosen photo-page 
    })
```